# Displaying a HTML field in PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a HTML field (wp_editor) that I have inputted via a WP_Editor style text area.

However I have just noticed that when I am trying to display the field it is coming up with the code like `"<ui>"` `"<li>"` etc.
The field is within a shortcode in PHP.

Any suggestions as to how to display it?

```
echo do_shortcode('
                [tabs slidertype="top tabs"]
                    [tabcontainer]
                        [tabtext] Event Details [/tabtext]
                        [tabtext] Sponsors [/tabtext]
                        [tabtext] Terms & Conditions [/tabtext]
                        [tabtext] Event Dcouments [/tabtext]
                    [/tabcontainer]
                    [tabcontent]
                        [tab] '. $EM_Event->output ('#_EVENTNOTES') .' [/tab]
                        [tab] '. $EM_Event->output ('#_ATT{Sponsors}') .' [/tab]
                        [tab] '. $EM_Event->output('#_ATT{Terms}') .' [/tab]
                        [tab] '. $tab_document_url .' [/tab]
                    [/tabcontent]
                [/tabs]
            '); ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: add `wordpress` tag to this question

Answer (score 0):

Try to display every tag one by one

```
<?= do_shortcode('[tabs slidertype="top tabs"]'); ?>
<?= do_shortcode('[tabcontainer]'); ?>
...
<?= do_shortcode('[/tabs]'); ?>
```

or link to other solutions:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162876/multiple-do-shortcode-in-page-template